# Failed to call function in a list of functions

Tags: c++

I have following C++ code that store 2 function in a list and later on call then inside list:

```
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

typedef void (*fp)();

void simpletest1(){
    cout << "test1";
}

void simpletest2(){
    cout << "test2";
}

int main()
{

    list<fp> generalHandlers;
    generalHandlers.push_back(simpletest1);
    generalHandlers.push_back(simpletest2);
    for (auto it = generalHandlers.begin(); it != generalHandlers.end(); ++it){
        (*it)();
    }


    return 0;
}
```

However after compile and run, it doesn't print out anything, and just terminate in 1 second. What is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried flushing the output buffer?

Comment: ohh it worked! The code has nothing wrong

Comment: What IDE are you using? Try codeBlocks, it holds the screen after the termination of program. Your code is working fine on  my setup.

Comment: I am just using terminal and sublime text, thanks for the suggestion tho

Comment: thx everyone, this code works perfectly for me now. Tips for anyone having similar issue: always call endl to flush output so that you will see debug information printed out if your program is still running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me, although I replaced 'list' with 'std::vector'. Maybe you just aren't noticing the output since you didn't add 'endl' after your cout statements?

Answer (score 2):

The code is perfectly valid, so the problem lies elsewhere;
Perhaps you should try pausing your program before it exits so you could actually read what's in the output. Also flushing the `cout` buffer with `std::endl` could help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to flush your output buffer.  Try either:

```
void simpletest1(){
    cout << "test1" << endl;
}

void simpletest2(){
    cout << "test2" << endl;
}
```

Or, leave your functions alone and flush from `main`:

```
int main()
{
    list<fp> generalHandlers;
    generalHandlers.push_back(simpletest1);
    generalHandlers.push_back(simpletest2);
    for (auto it = generalHandlers.begin(); it != generalHandlers.end(); ++it){
        (*it)();
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```